# Not understanding a compiler warning when using strcmp and strcpy

Tags: c, debugging, compiler-construction, warnings

I'm relatively new to C language programming. I'm trying to program a School Record Management System for a school project. I understand your policy with regards to the "I'm not going to do your homework for you" so I will not ask how to do everything though I will provide the entire code I'm working on. The problem I'm facing at the moment is that I'm using strcpy and strcmp to prevent the user from assigning an already existing ID to a new student, but the compiler shows a warning/problem that I don't quite understand.

Here is the **compiler log**:

```
Compiler: TDM-GCC 4.7.1 64-bit Release
Executing gcc.exe...
gcc.exe "C:\Users\Sheng\Desktop\Restarting Project\ToStudent\Updated_StudentManagement System.c" 
-o "C:\Users\Sheng\Desktop\Restarting Project\ToStudent\Updated_Student Management System.exe"   
-I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include"
-L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib"
-static-libgcc C:\Users\Sheng\Desktop\Restarting Project\ToStudent\Updated_StudentManagement System.c:
In function 'add_student':
C:\Users\Sheng\Desktop\Restarting Project\ToStudent\Updated_Student Management
**System.c:222:4: warning: passing argument 1 of 'strcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]**
In file included from C:\Users\Sheng\Desktop\Restarting Project\ToStudent\Updated_Student Management System.c:8:0:

**c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/string.h:51:18: note: expected 'char * __restrict__' but argument is of type 'char'**
C:\Users\Sheng\Desktop\Restarting Project\ToStudent\Updated_Student Management
**System.c:222:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'strcpy' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]**
In file included from C:\Users\Sheng\Desktop\Restarting Project\ToStudent\Updated_Student Management System.c:8:0:
c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-**mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/string.h:51:18: note: expected 'const char * __restrict__' but argument is of type 'char (*)[50]'**
C:\Users\Sheng\Desktop\Restarting Project\ToStudent\Updated_Student Management 
**System.c:227:5: warning: passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]**
In file included from C:\Users\Sheng\Desktop\Restarting Project\ToStudent\Updated_Student Management System.c:8:0:
**c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/string.h:53:15: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'char'
C:\Users\Sheng\Desktop\Restarting Project\ToStudent\Updated_Student Management System.c:227:5: warning: passing argument 2 of 'strcmp' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]**
In file included from C:\Users\Sheng\Desktop\Restarting Project\ToStudent\Updated_Student Management System.c:8:0:
**c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/string.h:53:15: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'char (*)[50]'**

Execution terminated
Compilation successful
```

**Code**:

```
struct Student
{
int num_student;            // number of students
char student_name[50][50];      // name of students
char student_id[50][50];        // Student ID
int student_course_num[10];     // Number of course each student enroll
int student_course[20][20];     // The course code of the student 
};

void add_student()
{
FILE *filePointer;
int i;
int user_input;
int j;
int replay = FALSE;
char testID[50];
struct Student profile[20];

printf("---------------------------------------------------\n");
printf("Option 3: Adding a Student\n");
printf("---------------------------------------------------\n");
printf("\n");

filePointer = fopen("Student.txt","a+");
if(filePointer == NULL)
{
printf("\nSystem Error...");
printf("\nPress any key to exit");
getch();
}
else
{
    printf("Enter the number of students to be added: ");
    scanf("%d",&user_input);
    for(i=0;i<user_input;i++)
    {
        if(TRUE && replay == FALSE)
        {
        printf("Enter Student Name: ");
        clearBuffer();
        scanf("%[^\n]",profile[i].student_name);
        }

        if(TRUE || replay == TRUE)
        {
        printf("Enter Student ID (8 digits): ");
        clearBuffer();
        scanf("%[^\n]",profile[i].student_id);
        }

        strcpy(testID[i],profile[i].student_id);

            for(j=0;j<i;j++)
            {

            if(strcmp(testID[j],profile[i].student_id) == 0)
                {
                    printf("The ID already exists");
                    i--;
                    replay = TRUE;  
                }
            }

        if(replay == FALSE)
        {
        fprintf(filePointer,"%s\n%s\n",profile[i].student_name,profile[i].student_id);
        }   
    }
}
fclose(filePointer);
return_menu();
```

}

Comment: Could you show us what warning you're getting?

Comment: You should post the warning.

Comment: next time you post a question (you are very welcome to do this), please try to strip the code to the minimum to show the problem.

Comment: fetch the K&R (aka the bible or "Programming in C") and read the chapters about arrays and strings.

Comment: I've rollback your replacement of the question by a solution. Please find [your solution in the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/bcce5a20-13be-4daf-9fa4-3ba10bfdb9c5/view-source) and post it as an answer of its own.

Answer (score 1):

Your Problem: testID is a `char[50]` so `testID[i]` is a single char (which is a small integer). `strcpy()` wants as first parameter a pointer. So you make an Integer from an Pointer (without cast).

if you want to have many testIDs with a fixed maximum-size, your declaration should be something like `char testID[50][100];` 
and please try to `#define` some constants for these values!

Comment: both strcmp and strcpy are used badly. It is also difficult to understand what he wanted to achieve, he may wanted char testID[][]

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I'm posting my comments correctly (very new to this.) Could you explain why use a two dimensional array? And is the 100 arbitrary?

Comment: a "char" is a single character. "char[50]" is an array of 50 chars (this is widely called a string, if the charactzer finalizing is an '\0' (zero)), so you can store texts up to 49 characters into one of these. And if you want to have a lot (like 100) of those strings you have to write "char[50][100];".

Comment: Ok, so I think I understand what you mean. The first part of the array designates the length of 1 string while the other part would determine how many of these I would store. If that were the case though then I dont't understand why the compiler says that the second argument in strcpy and strcmp also has this problem. Does that mean that I need to make profile 2 dimensional as well?

Comment: the second part has the vise-versa problem: your "profile[i].student_name" is of type "char[50][50]", so cou cast a "pointer of pointer" to "pointer of char" without cast

Answer (score 0):

The warnings are because Second argument to `strcmp() or strcpy()` must be a null terminated `char array` (string) or a char pointer.

You are passing it a `char **` i.e a double array as student_id is an array of arrays.

check these out :

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/